# Change CSS class based on date with js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table of dates that I am trying to highlight the current line based on the date.
and change the class of the previously active row to past.

As you can see the first row the class has been set to past, the second row is active and all future rows are future.

I found a js snippet that seems like it will work but I am having no luck getting it to work

I am not well versed in JS so if anyone can offer assistance to get this working I sure would appreciate it.
TIA
Steve

Here are the next few table rows.

```
  <TR class="past">
      <TD>1909</TD>
      <TD>Aug - 06</TD>
      <TD>Aug - 15</TD></TR>
    <TR class="active">
      <TD>1910</TD>
      <TD>Sep - 03</TD>
      <TD>Sep - 12</TD></TR>
    <TR class="future">
      <TD>1911</TD>
      <TD>Oct - 01</TD>
      <TD>Oct - 10</TD></TR>
    <TR class="future">
      <TD>1912</TD>
      <TD>Oct - 29</TD>
      <TD>Nov - 07</TD></TR>
    <TR class="future">
      <TD>1913</TD>
      <TD>Nov - 26</TD>
      <TD>Dec - 05</TD>
```

and this is the JS that I am trying to get working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$( ".class" ).each(function() {

        var text=$(this).text();

        var res = text.split(" "); 
        var resta = res[1].split("/"); 
        var dd=resta[0];
        var mm=resta[1];
        var yy=resta[2];

var now_date = new Date(); //"now"
var duedate = new Date(mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yy);    
var diff = Math.abs(now_date-duedate); 
var each_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;//milliseconds in a day
var days = Math.round(diff / each_day);

if(days <= 0)
$(this).removeClass("future").addClass("active");
if(days <= -1)
$(this).removeClass("active").addClass("past");
         });
</script> -->
```

Comment: How are you getting the dates there to begin with? Are you hard-coding them into the HTML?

Comment: Yes the dates are all hard coded in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("TR").each(function() {
var elements = $(this).children();

//get the year
var year = elements[0].innerHTML;

//get the month and date of upper limit... the important month and date
var upperLimitMonth = elements[2].innerHTML.split(" ")[0];
var upperLimitDate = elements[2].innerHTML.split(" ")[2];


//create a string from the different parts
var upperDate = `${year}-${upperLimitMonth}-${upperLimitDate}`;

//convert the strings to date and then to seconds
upperDate = new Date(upperDate).getTime();

//get today's date and convert to seconds
var today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);


//compare dates
if (upperDate < today) {
  $(this).addClass("past");
} else if (upperDate == today) {
  $(this).addClass("present");
} else {
  $(this).addClass("future");
}

  });


});
```

```css
.past{
 color: red;
}

.present{
 color: green;
}

.future{
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <TR>
    <TD>1909</TD>
    <TD>Aug - 06</TD>
    <TD>Aug - 15</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1910</TD>
    <TD>Sep - 03</TD>
    <TD>Sep - 12</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1911</TD>
    <TD>Oct - 01</TD>
    <TD>Oct - 10</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1912</TD>
    <TD>Oct - 29</TD>
    <TD>Nov - 07</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>2019</TD>
    <TD>Nov - 26</TD>
    <TD>Sep - 15</TD>
  </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD>2020</TD>
    <TD>Nov - 26</TD>
    <TD>Sep - 15</TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```

Please let me know if you need further explanations. I have tried to add explanations to different lines as I wrote but I don't know if that's enough for you to understand. So ask questions where necessary.

The first snippet is the javascript, followed by the css and then the html

https://jsfiddle.net/sawyerrken/peg86o42/21/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I get an error when I run the snippet here but no real info to point it out.

Comment: it is saying invalid character on line 45 char 19  line 44 and 45 in the file are:                                                                                                                //create a string from the different parts
  var lowerDate = `${year}-${lowerLimitMonth}-${lowerLimitDate}`;
  var upperDate = `${year}-${upperLimitMonth}-${upperLimitDate}`;

Comment: Did you add the backticks? 
See those backticks that look like single quotation. Its a backtick, on my keyboard its before key 1 on the top row.

Comment: yes the back ticks are there they just didn't paste above. I tried it in my local host as well and still have the error. In my file all the TR classes are set to "future" in the table. So if I load the page the 1910 line should be green 1909 red and 1911 on blue but they all show blue.

Comment: Notice in my own html I removed the class attribute for all the TRs, because it isn't needed for the solution and it should be set dynamically based on the outcome of the data comparisons. Make that change in your html too and lets know the outcome.

Comment: Also click the "Run Code Snippet" button here under the code to see what the outcome looks like.

Comment: That was where I first  saw the error. I will try it with the class and see how it works thanks for the help its greatly appreciated, from the run code button I tried in several browsers  Error: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: Oh okay. I have placed it on jsfiddle so you can play around with it there.  https://jsfiddle.net/sawyerrken/peg86o42/

Comment: Thanks for putting it in jsfiddle. When I view it there I don't see an error. but all the TR are blue. Is there a way to show the values of the array and vars like a var_dump in php?

Comment: Yes, you can use console.log(variable_name)
You have to keep your browser console open

Comment: Ok I made a little progress. When I look at the year array. the first item can be ignored. item 2 is the important item. For instance in the row Sep03 - Sep12 if the date is after Sep 12 but before Oct 10 thein it would be active on Oct 11th it would become past and the next Row OCT 1 - OCT 10 would become active. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I don't completely follow the instance you've provided. If you can provide one more instance or also show a JS fiddle with a wider range of data and dates and what the expected outcome should be

Comment: sorry for the poor explanation I was rushing to go to work. If I look at the output in the console log - console.log(year = elements[2].innerHTML;); it shows the item that todays date should referenced in the calculations. If todays date is after the date shown then if should select the past css class  and if the date is the same it would be marked as active. All dates +1 day ahead would use the future css. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Okay its clear now and I have updated the code accordingly. I have also updated the jsfiddle. Please view the jsfiddle on Chrome (the solution will work across browsers for you, so no worries). Hope this helps.  https://jsfiddle.net/sawyerrken/peg86o42/21/